# Problem in Chapter 2 (Walter Rudin).

Tags: general-topology, analysis

"Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin has the following question:

> Show that the following statement is false in $\Bbb{R}$:
>
> If $\{K_\alpha\}$ is a collection of **closed** subsets of a metric space $X$ such that the intersection of every finite subcollection of $\{K_\alpha\}$ is nonempty, then $\bigcap K_\alpha$ is nonempty.

If every finite intersection is nonempty, this implies we can construct nested closed sets. Considering $\Bbb{R}$ is complete, shouldn't this intersection be **nonempty**? Why is this statement false?

Comment: Check the collection $\;\left\{K_n:=[n,\infty)\right\}\;$ ...

Comment: Ah you're right. Boundedness is also a pre-requisite.

Answer (score 3):

Because $\infty$ is not part of the real numbers. So set
$$
K_\alpha = [\alpha, \infty)
$$

Comment: "Because $\infty$ is not part of the real numbers." could be better put and/or explained!

Comment: This was in response to OP's remark that we have a nested sets. The problem is that the nested sets eventually "contain" $\infty$. Now if we extend the reals to include $\infty$ also, then the OP's remark will be true statement would be true.

Answer (score 0):

The example given in the other answer shows why it is false. Note that the diameters of these sets are all infinite. If indeed we have countably many such closed sets **and** their diameters tend to $0$ as well, then completeness will give a point in the intersection (as picking points in the intersections will give a Cauchy sequence). Maybe this is what confused you?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is correct is "bounded" is replaced by "compact".

Also, it is correct if $\mathbb R$ is replaced by "a compact metric space".